# Meaningless error message / stacktrace in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

This:

**saxios.specs.ts:**

```js
    test('Read names', async () => {
        const response = await rest.get<string>(PATH_NAMES, {
            headers: withTokenForGuest4.headers
        })
        const retvalue = JSON.stringify(response.data)

        logger.debug(JSON.stringify(response.data, undefined, 4))
        expect(retvalue).toStartWith('{"data":{"records":3')
    })
```

produces:

```sh
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (/Volumes/DevLocal/DevTypeScript/Production/mobiad/communication/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Volumes/DevLocal/DevTypeScript/Production/mobiad/communication/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Volumes/DevLocal/DevTypeScript/Production/mobiad/communication/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1224:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

??? This stacktrace has nothing to do with my test-Function.
I can guess which line produced the stacktrace but there is no reference back
to the line in my test-function...

Is there another way to get a better stacktrace?

**[Update]**

I tried what @ippi mentioned - almost same result

```sh
      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
```

Comment: It's not meaningless, 401 is an authentication error. Your request was returned by the server as unauthenticated.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but there is the up and coming --async-stack-traces. `"scripts": {
  "test": "node --async-stack-traces node_modules/.bin/jest"
}`  You need node v12 at least.

Comment: @Christian I know what 401 means but there is no reference to my test-function in the stacktrace. In this case I know it's the first line because that's the only line that could produce a 401 but imaging I had 3 async axios calls...

Comment: @ippi Thanks, but didn't help. I updated my question with the result